# HDMI out not working

Tags: boot, raspbian-wheezy, boot-issues

My HDMI output suddenly stopped working. It says no signal. No matter what I do. The PI boots up i think because the PWR light is on as well as 2 connected leds. I have crucial date and one script on the pi that I really can't lose. What can I do? I am running RASPIAN.

Comment: Ensure that your SD card is inserted correctly.

Comment: you can login over SSH and retrieve your data and script, but the script should be under version control and the data should be backed up.

Comment: You can mount the SD-card on your computer and copy the data and the script.

Answer (score 1):

If it involves data recovery,
(when you say there are scripts you cant loose...)
 image the drive first. Ill presume linux is your primary OS, in which case the command would be something like `ddrescue /dev/sdCardDevice MyPi.iso`
if you don't have ddrescue, get it, as it is far superior to `dd`
 which you could also use.

Please answer: is 
ssh up and running?

Are you more concerned about recovering data?

is there a screen with s-video you can use?

does your pi show up on your network?

did the ISO you produced have any errors while it was being generated?

That ISO file you created, should be mountable in linux, in which case, you can go retrieve your files. In the event your disk had some errors, you can also use data recovery tools on the image (like test disk)

I can walk you though either or both video troubleshooting or datarecovery, but I'll need more detail first.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried pressing the 1 or 2 buttons on the keyboard?

Lik j0h said you should plug the sd into a computer and run a disk imaging software

If you are running windows a good one is win32diskimager or also in linux dd rescue

And if you fix it you should make recovery images of your SD's it really helps :D